# Errors on Monodroid 4.0 using googlemaps

Tags: c#, macos, google-maps, xamarin.android

I'm trying to run the samples of xamarin about googlemaps, and the MapsDemo sample doesnt work. I'm trying to run on the Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 8 emulator, it throws me this error: Couldn't get connection factory client, and when im trying to run onGoogle APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 10 emulator:

W/System.err(  555): IOException processing: 26
W/System.err(  555): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)

and my apiKey is correct. Does anyone have this working with googlemaps with monodroid on mac? If you do, how can I solve this? Because I have already spent a long time trying to solve this one but I cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the whole Google Maps and API Key mess if you don't mind the user leaving your application and just run the app directly.  They can still hit the back key and end up in your application again.  The code to do this is:

```
Linkify.AddLinks(lblAddress, MatchOptions.MapAddresses);
```

However, this only works on a TextView.  If you want to do it on a button click, you'd have to do a bit more investigating.